# Configure AOSP Source code for development with android studio

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to configure android studio to work with AOSP source code, I followed many guides all are almost the same, but all gave me the same error, anyone please take a look and help me please....

I have followed -
https://shuhaowu.com/blog/setting_up_intellij_with_aosp_development.html
this guide as well as the official documentation.... still same error.
I am pasting the output here, also here a better view https://del.dog/gawiwicila.makefile Thank you

```
[rajssss@Rajssss pt1]$ b*/e*
including device/google/crosshatch/vendorsetup.sh
including vendor/dot/vendorsetup.sh
including sdk/bash_completion/adb.bash
[rajssss@Rajssss pt1]$ cd development/tools/idegen
[rajssss@Rajssss idegen]$ mm
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=9
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.19.28-1-MANJARO-x86_64-Manjaro-Linux
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=PQ2A.190405.003
OUT_DIR=/home/rajssss/pt1/out
============================================
[1/1] /home/rajssss/pt1/out/soong/.min...s/pt1/out/soong/.bootstrap/build.ninja
[55/56] glob prebuilts/ndk/cpufeatures.bp
[80/80] /home/rajssss/pt1/out/soong/.b...home/rajssss/pt1/out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: /home/rajssss/pt1/out/soong/build.ninja 
/home/rajssss/pt1/out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -l /home/rajssss/pt1/out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b /home/rajssss/pt1/out/soong -n /home/rajssss/pt1/out -d /home/rajssss/pt1/out/soong/build.ninja.d -o /home/rajssss/pt1/out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp
internal error: panic in GenerateBuildActions for singleton glob
error parsing variable "glob": invalid character after '$' at byte offset 1
goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/google/blueprint.newPanicErrorf(0x804060, 0xc4743fda80, 0xc4376eade0, 0x27, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x20, 0xc4210af498)
    /home/rajssss/pt1/build/blueprint/context.go:3462 +0x82
github.com/google/blueprint.(*Context).generateSingletonBuildActions.func1.1(0xc4210afb98, 0xc4741c0460)
    /home/rajssss/pt1/build/blueprint/context.go:2320 +0x396
panic(0x804060, 0xc4743fda80)
    prebuilts/go/linux-x86/src/runtime/panic.go:505 +0x229
github.com/google/blueprint.(*singletonContext).Build(0xc4741c0460, 0x9009e0, 0xc4200a6320, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /home/rajssss/pt1/build/blueprint/singleton_ctx.go:169 +0x16f
github.com/google/blueprint/bootstrap.GlobFile(0x7f3a6cc43810, 0xc4741c0460, 0xc434092e20, 0x20, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc474408280, 0x47, 0xc4744082d0, ...)
    /home/rajssss/pt1/build/blueprint/bootstrap/glob.go:72 +0x245
github.com/google/blueprint/bootstrap.(*globSingleton).GenerateBuildActions(0xc4201ae108, 0x905020, 0xc4741c0460)
    /home/rajssss/pt1/build/blueprint/bootstrap/glob.go:133 +0x3d6
github.com/google/blueprint.(*Context).generateSingletonBuildActions.func1(0xc4210afb98, 0xc4741c0460)
    /home/rajssss/pt1/build/blueprint/context.go:2324 +0x81
github.com/google/blueprint.(*Context).generateSingletonBuildActions(0xc42014f8c0, 0x88a460, 0xc4201c2500, 0xc420154580, 0xb, 0x10, 0xc429a87a10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /home/rajssss/pt1/build/blueprint/context.go:2325 +0x2a8
github.com/google/blueprint.(*Context).PrepareBuildActions(0xc42014f8c0, 0x88a460, 0xc4201c2500, 0x7f3a6dc8d1e0, 0xc4201c2500, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/rajssss/pt1/build/blueprint/context.go:1878 +0x12c
github.com/google/blueprint/bootstrap.Main(0xc42014f8c0, 0x88a460, 0xc4201c2500, 0xc420787f58, 0x3, 0x4)
    /home/rajssss/pt1/build/blueprint/bootstrap/command.go:164 +0x7d3
main.main()
    /home/rajssss/pt1/build/soong/cmd/soong_build/main.go:75 +0x26d


ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
09:41:29 song bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (31 seconds) ####
```